# Kafka broker precedence

Tags: apache-kafka

If I have a global configuration with EMEA, APAC and NYC instances of a particular application, I am looking at having regional Kafka brokers, all replicating from a central single topic that they all use for input and another for output data.

What I would like though, is for each regional instance of my application to communicate with the broker for it's region - as a NYC application speaking to a London broker would add a lot of latency.

Is there a way to do this with Kafka configuration? As I understand it if you have three brokers across three regions with a single topic, one broker will be the primary and the others will be replicated.

1) Does this still mean though that I can connect to the local broker only and read the data without having to use a different regions broker, whether the local broker is leader or replicated?

2) For failover, say if the NYC broker goes down, I would like the application to be able to then as a secondary resort, try one of the other regions - though it would want to switch back to the local region if it came back online. Is this possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a topic with 3 partitions and for each message use a different key (one of `emea`, `apac`, `nyc`) in order to force the messages to be placed on partitions based on the location of the application. Alternatively, you can force your application instances to push messages to a specific partition - for example, the instance running in NYC will push messages to partition 0 etc.

Now to achieve this, [Replication Tools](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Replication+tools) might be useful. When a new topic is created in Kafka, you only need to define the number of partitions and replication factor, while Kafka automatically handles their distribution across the cluster. You can force this assignment though, using the replication tools;

> **2.2 Create Topics**
>  What does the tool do? 
> By default, Kafka auto creates topic if "auto.create.topics.enable" is set to true on the
>   server. This creates a topic with a default number of partitions,
>   replication factor and uses Kafka's default scheme to do replica
>   assignment. Sometimes, it may be required that we would like to
>   customize a topic while creating it. This tool helps to create a topic
>   and also specify the number of partitions, replication factor and
>   replica assignment list for the topic.
>
> How to use the tool?
>
> ```
> # Create topic with default settings
> bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic topic1
>
> # Create topic with specific number of partitions and/or replicas
> bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic topic1 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 3
>
>
> # Create topic with manual replica assignment
> bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic topic1 --replica-assignment 0:1:2,0:1:2,0:1:2
>
> # Create topic with configuration override
> bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic topic1 --config min.insync.replicas=1
> ```
>
> **2.3 Add Partition to Topic**
>  
>   What does the tool do?
>  
>   In Kafka partitions act as the unit of parallelism: messages of a single topic are
>   distributed to multiple partitions that can be stored and served on
>   different servers. Upon creation of a topic, the number of partitions
>   for this topic has to be specified. Later on more partitions may be
>   needed for this topic when the volume of this topic increases. This
>   tool helps to add more partitions for a specific topic and also allow
>   manual replica assignment of the added partitions.
>
> How to use the tool?
>
> ```
> # Increase number of partitions for topic
> bin/kafka-topics.sh --alter --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic topic1 --partitions 4
>
> # Increase number of partitions with specific replica assignment
> bin/kafka-topics.sh --alter --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic topic1 --replica-assignment 0:1:2,0:1:2,0:1:2,2:1:0 --partitions 4
> ```

To answer your questions now;

1) If the `--replication-factor` is set to 1 then you will be able to read data from a broker in NYC, if you define the host of that broker. If you set `--replication-factor` to 3, then you will be able to consume the messages from any of the brokers available.

2) When the NYC broker fails, then another broker will become the partition leader. [This is automatically handled by Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/intro#intro_distribution):

> The partitions of the log are distributed over the servers in the
>   Kafka cluster with each server handling data and requests for a share
>   of the partitions. Each partition is replicated across a configurable
>   number of servers for fault tolerance.
>
> Each partition has one server which acts as the "leader" and zero or
>   more servers which act as "followers". The leader handles all read and
>   write requests for the partition while the followers passively
>   replicate the leader. If the leader fails, one of the followers will
>   automatically become the new leader. Each server acts as a leader for
>   some of its partitions and a follower for others so load is well
>   balanced within the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any manual way to assign brokers/partitions at run time? So lets say each partition is assigned a key (not sure if EMEA/APAC/US would actually hash to different partitions but lets assume so) and each regional broker was manually configured to be the leader for that partition (What is the syntax for the replica-assignment? Above you just put 0:1:2,0:1:2,0:1:2 which seems to be the same for each broker, so what do the number relate to?). But say thats all so, then one broker goes down and zookeper switches you over to one of the other regions..... contd

Comment: NYC then comes back up - I assume I'd have to manually have some watcher heartbeat process globally listening for this somehow, and then re-assign the partitions once NYC was back up so that normal order was restored and people were once again speaking to the correct brokers

Comment: Also, could I potentially implement this as a cluster per region, each with the same two topics, using Kafka Replicator between them to keep in sync?

Comment: @NZJames This would be the best option. Setup 3 different clusters (one per region) and use Kafka MirrorMaker to synchronize the clusters.

Comment: Ok, is that the preferred tool to Kafka Replicator?

Comment: As far as I know you have 3 options; [Kafka MirrorMaker](https://docs.confluent.io/current/multi-dc-replicator/mirrormaker.html), [Confluent Replicator](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-replicator/index.html) and [ureplicator](https://github.com/uber/uReplicator) which is an improved edition of MirrorMaker implemented by Uber.